# Garbage Collection issues on MapPartitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I currently have a mapPartitions job which is flatMapping each value in the
iterator, and I'm running into an issue where there will be major GC costs
on certain executions. Some executors will take 20 minutes, 15 of which are
pure garbage collection, and I believe that a lot of it has to do with the
ArrayBuffer that I am outputting. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how
I can do some form of a stream output?

Also, does anyone have any advice in general for tracking down/addressing GC
issues in spark?

Comment: "believe that a lot of it has to do with the ArrayBuffer that I am outputting." Since we know nothing about how you are using it, not sure how much anyone can help here. What leads to you to believe it's the ArrayBuffer? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below documentation from official page of Spark tuning. I hope it will at least help to give direction to your analysis:

Memory Management Overview
Memory usage in Spark largely falls under one of two categories: execution and storage. Execution memory refers to that used for computation in shuffles, joins, sorts and aggregations, while storage memory refers to that used for caching and propagating internal data across the cluster. In Spark, execution and storage share a unified region (M). When no execution memory is used, storage can acquire all the available memory and vice versa. Execution may evict storage if necessary, but only until total storage memory usage falls under a certain threshold (R). In other words, R describes a subregion within M where cached blocks are never evicted. Storage may not evict execution due to complexities in implementation.

This design ensures several desirable properties. First, applications that do not use caching can use the entire space for execution, obviating unnecessary disk spills. Second, applications that do use caching can reserve a minimum storage space (R) where their data blocks are immune to being evicted. Lastly, this approach provides reasonable out-of-the-box performance for a variety of workloads without requiring user expertise of how memory is divided internally.

Although there are two relevant configurations, the typical user should not need to adjust them as the default values are applicable to most workloads:

spark.memory.fraction expresses the size of M as a fraction of the (JVM heap space - 300MB) (default 0.6). The rest of the space (40%) is reserved for user data structures, internal metadata in Spark, and safeguarding against OOM errors in the case of sparse and unusually large records.
spark.memory.storageFraction expresses the size of R as a fraction of M (default 0.5). R is the storage space within M where cached blocks immune to being evicted by execution.
The value of spark.memory.fraction should be set in order to fit this amount of heap space comfortably within the JVM’s old or “tenured” generation. See the discussion of advanced GC tuning below for details.